# Nexus 5 not getting net data even though its having hspa+ range

Tags: nexus-5, mobile-network

I tried rebooting my phone, reset to default on APN , safe mode but nothing seems to work.I still dont get internet on my phone.I'm from India and connection  is docomo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Settings > More > Mobile Networks > "Use only 2G Networks"

Make sure the above option is unchecked and you've correctly activated a proper 3G plan. Also, don't forget to configure the APN for using the internet.

Comment: Im using 3g for the past three months since i bought the phone.And its in LTE mode.